# What does pageRequestTimeout exactly mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, automated-tests, testcafe

`pageRequestTimeout. Specifies time (in milliseconds) to wait for HTML pages. If TestCafe does not receive a page within the specified period, it throws an error.`

This documentation is still not clear to me what is exactly testcafe waits for there?

testcafe: 2.5.0
node: v16.19.0
browser: chrome

I have issues saying and trying to figure out the exact reason.

```
Failed to load the page at "https://xxx/".
      Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the "retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.
      You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".
      Error details:
      Failed to complete a request to "https://xxx/" within the timeout period. The problem may be related to local machine's network or firewall settings, server outage, or network problems that make the server inaccessible.
```

pageRequestTimeout is 30000, quarantine mode is on. What's happening is the site is loading and after timeout period testcafe just redirects me to blank "about:error" page. Manually the site opens fine.

Answer (score 1):

The pageRequestTimeout option in TestCafe specifies the time duration (in milliseconds) for which TestCafe waits for an HTML page to load before timing out and throwing an error. In your case, it seems that TestCafe is not able to load the page at the specified URL within the timeout period of 30 seconds, and hence it is throwing the error.

The error message suggests that the problem may be related to the local machine's network or firewall settings, server outage, or network problems that make the server inaccessible. It is possible that the page you are trying to load is taking longer to load due to network issues or server problems, or that your local machine's firewall settings are blocking the page from loading.

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try increasing the value of the pageRequestTimeout option, enabling the retryTestPages option, or using quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute the test. You can also try accessing the page manually to check if it loads correctly and if there are any network or firewall issues on your machine.

Comment: 'waits for an HTML page to load' what exactly does it mean? Why did you just copy the same things as I wrote? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the description in the official documentation - https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#pagerequesttimeout. If the page works correctly without TestCafe, then it can be a TestCafe issue. In this case, you can create an issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository.